# generatation of ARQC multiple times in a single Card dip

Tags: cryptography, emv, iso8583

I have a question regarding ARQC generation. Can I generate ARQC multiple times in a single Card dip ? For example if we initiate  a PIN validation transaction and at successful response I initiate account relationship inquiry transaction. So I will need 2 different ARQC for both transaction with single card dip. Is it Possible or not ?

Answer (score 0):

No. After a GPO you can initiate a max of two GEN ACs . Any further try will get declined from card.

Comment: You may, however, issue another GPO (that will also increment ATC) and have possibility to generate another cryptogram.

Comment: @MichalGluchowski yes

Comment: OK, Can you guyz provide me sample data for ARQC and ARPC ?

Comment: Input for ARQC is data elements of CDOL1 and input for GEN AC 2 is CDOL2. For ARPC calculation you need to check how each payment schemes requires, generally it is ARQC xor ARC